# Indefinite for loop not working in C

Tags: c, dev-c++

I'm currently reading Beginning C by Ivor Horton. Anyways my indefinite `for` is printing my `printf` statement twice before moving on. I'm sure I'm doing something wrong but I copied the code right from the book. I'm using Dev-C++ if that matters. Here is the code... Thanks

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>  // For tolower() function  //

int main(void)
{
char answer = 'N';
double total = 0.0;  // Total of values entered //
double value = 0.0;  // Value entered //
int count = 0;

printf("This program calculates the average of"
                       " any number of values.");
for( ;; )
{
    printf("\nEnter a value: ");
    scanf("%lf", &value);
    total+=value;
    ++count;

    printf("Do you want to enter another value? (Y or N): ");
    scanf("%c", &answer);

    if(tolower(answer) == 'n')
        break;
}

printf("The average is %.2lf.", total/count);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Looks fine: http://codepad.org/05iK44DP

Comment: This program calculates the average of any number of values.      Enter a value: 5                                                            Do you want to enter another value?(Y or N):                                Enter a value:                                                          As you can see it skips right over the scanf and I'm not sure why... Thanks again

Comment: The value of `answer` defaults to `'N'`, im not familiar with `scanf()` but if for some reason it dont overwrite the variable, the loop breaking condition will be true.

Comment: Rule of thumb with C. It's never the compiler. Ever.

Comment: Funny thing is I'm 150 pages into the book and this was the first time I messed that up.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If we briefly run through your program, here's what will happen:

1. It prompts the user to type a number.
2. The user enters a number and presses enter.
3. `scanf` reads the number, but leaves the newline in the queue.
4. It prompts the user to type Y or N.
5. It tries to read a character, but does not skip any whitespace/newlines, so it ends up consuming the newline that was left in the queue.

Obviously, we need to skip over the newline. Fortunately, that's rather easy, if non-obvious: add a space to the start of the format string, e.g.:

```
scanf(" %c", &answer);
```

A space in the format string means “skip as much whitespace as possible before reading the next thing”. This is done automatically for most conversions, but not for strings or characters.

Comment: Shouldn't it skip in the first scanf where its reading the number?

Comment: @Havenard: Whoops, I missed that, but the problem remains: reading the number will only skip enough whitespace to get to the start of the number. After the number has been read, whitespace remains.

Comment: Wow. Thank you so much! I didn't even realize that a space would matter.

Answer (score 2):

Change this line

```
scanf("%c", &answer);
```

to

```
scanf(" %c", &answer);
```

The space will cause scanf to ignore whitespace preceding the character you enter.

The whitespace is a consequence of striking Enter after providing the number.

Answer (score -1):

Code is fine, only thing that has been missed is `fflush(stdin)`; before `scanf` function.
It may be used always before `scanf` function to avoid these pitfalls.
The act of pressing 'Enter' key gives new line character '\n' as input to the stdin buffer. Hence the first scanf function in the loop assumes it as input and doesn't wait for the user to key in the values.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>  // For tolower() function  //

int main(void)
{
char answer = 'N';
double total = 0.0;  // Total of values entered //
double value = 0.0;  // Value entered //
int count = 0;

printf("This program calculates the average of"
                       " any number of values.");
while(1)
{
    printf("\nEnter a value: ");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%lf", &value);
    total+=value;
    ++count;

    printf("Do you want to enter another value? (Y or N): ");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%c", &answer);
    if(tolower(answer) == 'n')
        break;
}

printf("The average is %.2lf.", total/count);
getch();
return 0;
}
```

Also add a `getch()` function to view results, if you are using console.

Comment: `fflush(stdin)` causes undefined behavior.